# gvim 8.2 windows10 _gvimrc location

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I am using gvim. I have checked the location of the RUNTIMEFILE with :echo $RUNTIMEFILE and found that is is located in c:\Programme\vim\vim82.

The file _gvimrc is there indeed. However, I do not have administrator privileges and I cannot write to this directory.

I would prefer to have my _gvimrc in a different directory. I do not find a way of ensuring that gvim finds my personal _gvimrc.

I may ask the administrator once to set a PATH, but I cannot expect continuous support for every edit of _gvimrc.

I have seen many related questions, but none is addressing the issue of no-access to the directory vim82.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Check out the output of the `:version` command, it's possible that the `_gvimrc` you're seeing under `vim\vim82` is the *system* gvimrc file and not the user gvimrc file. Note also that for most settings you want them set in the `vimrc` file and not the `gvimrc`. Use the `gvimrc` file mostly for settings related to fonts or mouse, that are only applicable to the GUI version of Vim. The `vimrc` file is loaded much earlier than the `gvimrc` file, so there are many settings that will *only* work in `vimrc`.

Comment: As @filbranden says, I would assume from `:help vimrc` that you want `MS-Windows $HOME/_vimrc, $HOME/vimfiles/vimrc`

Comment: As a frequent gvim user I can confirm those paths from DBK are what you want. I use `c:\Users\{myname}\_vimrc` and, only for a few GUI things (e.g. `'guifont'` and `'guioptions'`), `c:\Users\{myname}\_gvimrc`. Using `_gvimrc` allows me to symlink my cygwin `.vimrc` to `_vimrc` without having to use things like `has("win32")` or whatever.